# Logging to JTA from Struts2 log4j2

Tags: java, mysql, log4j2, jta

I am trying to log my issues to mysql database using Log4j2. I am working on a Struts2 web application. my hosting server is glassfish. i am using netbeans for my ide and this project is not using maven. my problem is that i have configured log4j.properties file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error">
  <Appenders>
    <JPA name="databaseAppender" persistenceUnitName="MyWebPU"
        entityClassName="com.myproject.web.logging.ErrorLogEntity" />
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
       <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

While i put under Web pages->WEB-INF folder in netbeans project. 
I have also edited web.xml file in the same folder with the below lines :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I couldn't find a reference about the mysql table structure so sorted out (i hope) this will be the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `errorlog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  `class` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

my persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="TravelBeiWebPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>travelbeilogs</jta-data-source>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextMapAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextMapJsonAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextStackAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextStackJsonAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.MarkerAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.MessageAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.StackTraceElementAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ThrowableAttributeConverter</class>
    <class>com.myproject.web.logging.ErrorLogEntity</class>    
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am not able to make it work.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error, it seams log4j2 is not getting my property file, it writes the error to glassfish log file